# Ajax appending the data to previous data?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, gson

`index.jsp`

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="show(this.value)" />
<div id="output"></div>   
<script type="text/javascript">

   function show(cat)
   {
       var output = document.getElementById("output");

       $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:"fetchdata",
           data:"cat="+cat,
           success:function(responseJson){
               output.innerHTML = responseJson;
           } 
       });   
   }
```

`fetchdata.java`

```
public class fetchdata extends HttpServlet {
    Connection con =null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> pname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> iname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> cname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Double> price = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dealtime","root","root");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("Select images.product_name,image_name,company_name,price "
                + "from images,products where images.product_name = products.product_name AND "
                + " category_name = ?");

        ps.setString(1,cat);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();          
        while(rs.next())
        {
            pname.add(rs.getString("product_name"));
            iname.add(rs.getString("image_name"));
            cname.add(rs.getString("company_name"));
            price.add(rs.getDouble("price"));
        }

        String json =new Gson().toJson(pname);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        out.println(json);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(fetchdata.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

}

The above code is working fine but when multiple ajax request are made the data is appended to the data which I received from the previous ajax request. I just want to update the `div` with new data only and also I want to know how to send multiple objects as a response and manipulate them to extract values from it.

Comment: None of this really makes sense. You are treating a json response as html and when you do `output.innerHTML = responseJson;` there is no append, the previous html is replaced

Comment: @charlietfl yes it must replace the previous html but I don't know why its not doing the same.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. Also `cat` in `show()` is not even defined. Are you sure you aren't getting errors in browser console? Code shown should fail

Comment: how can I create a demo?

Comment: Sorry this is just a typo I have updated it

Comment: Can you show more of fetchdata.java, specifically where your variables are defined? If pname etc are instance properties and not method scope, then you are likely adding additional values to whatever this variable is every time you call this code via your Ajax call.

Comment: @KevinHooke updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlets are multithreaded, meaning the Servlet container will instantiate a small number of instances, but run multiple threads (one per request) through each instance. Properties defined on the Servlet class as instance properties will therefore share state between all threads (requests) that execute through that instance.

If you instantiate a class (call new on it), the instance properties are visible to all methods in that class, their values are shared. For a Servlet, the servlet container creates at minimum 1 instance of the Servlet, and then for performance reasons executes 1 thread per incoming request through that instance of the servlet. This means that each executing thread is able to see the values in the instance properties. Moving the properties within the scope of a method means that each thread has their own copy.

Move the declaration of all your properties from the instance level to within the doGet() method, then the state will no longer be shared. It's usually bad practice to share state on a Servlet in this way.

This behavior is explained in the EE tutorial here - see 17.3.2:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets003.htm#BNAFO

Also, rather than creating your own JDBC connections, it's best practice to define a Datasource on your servlet container (how you do that depends on what you are running), and let the app server manage the connections for you. You just pull a connection from the datasource when needed.

To answer the second part of the question, you can structure your json like this to include multiple properties in the response:

```
{
    "pname" : "pname value",
    "iname" : "iname value"
    //etc
}
```

If any of these properties themselves have properties, nested objects, then just create another Json object as the value of one of the properties.

Comment: thanks it worked but can you explain the why part a little bit more.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you enlighten me on the second part of the question

Comment: added some more detail - let me know if this helps?

Comment: thanks it helped. Can you also tell me how to send multiple objects in response as I also want to send the `iname` , `cname` and `price` to the ajax call.